# how can i remove all characters in list item after "-" python and convert that item data type to float?

Tags: python

I have a list of items in python

```
lst=["2.6","2-3","7-8","9","10-11","1 Year","2 Weeks"]
```

I have to remove everything after "-"

Expected list i want

```
lst=[2.6,2.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,"1 Year","2 Weeks"]
```

How can i achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using regular expressions:

```
import re

def one_elem(elem):
    if re.fullmatch('\d+', elem):
        return float(elem)
    if re.fullmatch('\d+\.\d+', elem):
        return float(elem)
    if re.fullmatch('\d+-\d+', elem):
        return float(elem.split('-')[0])

    return elem

lst=["2.6","2-3","7-8","9","10-11","1 Year","2 Weeks"]
lst = [one_elem(elem) for elem in lst]
lst
```

Result:

```
[2.6, 2.0, 7.0, 9.0, 10.0, '1 Year', '2 Weeks']
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to do the conversion:

```
def convert(value):
    try:
        return float(value.split('-', 1))
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

Then use it:

```
result = [convert(value) for value in lst]
```

Or even:

```
result = list(map(convert, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

**For fun**, a list comprehension to do both the `split` and conversion to `float` (I wouldn't really use this is in a project as it's less than explicit!):

```
[float(n) if (n:=s.split('-',1)[0]).replace('.','',1).isdigit() else s for s in lst]
```

*NB. requires python ≥3.8.*

Output: `[2.6, 2.0, 7.0, 9.0, 10.0, '1 Year', '2 Weeks']`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=["2.6","2-3","7-8","9","10-11","1 Year","2 Weeks"] #your original list
fixedlst = [] # your new fixed list

for stuff in lst:  

if "-" in stuff:
    #from elements that contain - only!

    x = stuff.replace("-", ".").split(".")[0] #getting rid of - to . and removing everything after .
    fixedlst.append(float(x))  #adding it to the new list as float so it adds .0 at the end


if "-" not in stuff:
    #for elements that dont contain -
    
    try:
        fixedlst.append(float(stuff))  # converting all numerical strings to float

    except ValueError:
        fixedlst.append(stuff) # returning non-numerical strings as they are


#I did this in 2 steps so i dont remove the original numbers        

print(fixedlst)
```

your output would be:

```
[2.6, 2.0, 7.0, 9.0, 10.0, '1 Year', '2 Weeks']
```